# Autolayout constraints not working

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to follow the Autolayouts tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) and configured my View to have all the constraints from the tutorial yet, my actual view, when rendered, looks like crap.

Constraints:
[image: Constraints]

Rendered View, Portrait:
[image]
Rendered View, Landscape:
[image]

What am I missing? I have used UIImageViews instead of UIViews because in XCode 6 I havent found a way to set the background color on a view. But that's a whole another question.

Comment: set vertical space between upper views and below view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a vertical constraint between the upper cat UIImageViews and the bottom UIImageView.You missed it. so they are stretched to screen height in the vertical.